# Variables in SAP MII

Tags: properties, transactions, local, workbench, sap-mii

Basically, am looking for a variable/Property that holds the value even outside of the transaction execution facilitating to use in the next rounds of execution, similar to a counter in any programming language until it get reset explicitly.

As seen in SAP MII, Local and Transaction properties are reset on completion of transaction execution, leaving all the properties to initial state, without giving any opportunity to use the stored/assigned value in previous transaction. Global properties are not GOOD for such requirement as they are Read-Only.

Did any one use such property/tried for any work around?

Thanks

Comment: I suggest using a shared property.

Answer (score 0):

You can use session variables for this

To store a variable:

`/XMII/PropertyAccessServlet?mode=store&PropName=<name>&PropValue=<value>`

and to read the variable:

`/XMII/PropertyAccessServlet?mode=retrieve&PropName=<name>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared properties. I use it as a way to keep track of the number of times a transaction has been run. The persistent shared property is stored in a database, so it won't disappear after the transaction ends.

[https://help.sap.com/saphelp_mii151sp03/helpdata/en/4c/72e4f8e631469ee10000000a15822d/content.htm?no_cache=true#:~:text=Shared%20Memory%20You%20use%20the%20Shared%20Memoryscreen%20to,are%20migrated%20with%20a%20project%20are%20not%20overwritten](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_mii151sp03/helpdata/en/4c/72e4f8e631469ee10000000a15822d/content.htm?no_cache=true#:%7E:text=Shared%20Memory%20You%20use%20the%20Shared%20Memoryscreen%20to,are%20migrated%20with%20a%20project%20are%20not%20overwritten).